# laravel form serialize and file upload

Tags: laravel, forms, serialization

Hi i don't understand why in my form serialize doesn't work. I use ajax to upload file

My blade is

```
  <form class="form-inline" id="uploadFileFrm">
     @csrf
     <select class="form-control ml-4" id="tas" name="tas">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Seleziona tas</option>
      @isset($users)
       @foreach ($users as $user)
        <option value="{{ $user->id }}">
         {{ $user->code }} - {{ $user->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
      @endisset
     </select>

     <div class="custom-file col-6 ml-4">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile"></label>
      <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Carica il planning selezionando prima il tas</small>
     </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-4" id="importFile">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

then my javascript is

```
  $(document).on("click", '#importFile', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = $('#uploadFileFrm').serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     url: "{{ url('/uploadfile') }}",
     data: data,
     success: function(data) {
      .........
     }
    }); //fine ajax
   });
```

it serialize only token
in Chrome debug infact i see only

```
_token=N5HD2apC6VH5T7YAgXqgNT209zk2DmTdddm0JXcf
```

and nothing about TAS and FILE
Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **multipart** in `<form>` tag -

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFileFrm">
```

Change AJAX call like this -

```
$('#uploadFileFrm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ url('/uploadfile') }}",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: (data) => {
            this.reset();
            alert('File has been uploaded successfully');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow it works!!, but which was my error? Why serialize doesn't work :(

Comment: @MarcoBozzola you forgot to add 'multipart' in form tag and when you are using serialize to submit  form with ajax call, no need to add contentType and processData, cache.